# Project containing jni file

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to import an android project to my Eclipse.
When i run this project, i got an error, "library is null".
I figured out that this project was different, it contain a file named "jni". My library is in that file.
I guess the library in this file was never compiled (i don't know why)
I have seen in some topic that i need to use NDK?
Did any one have a clear answer about this?

Comment: You have to compile jni folder using ndk-build command from cygwin terminal. This create ".so" file in libs folder.

Comment: i am using my mac book, no need to install cygwin.

Comment: Do you have a link indicating what command i have to lunch

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below links. [link to download ndk](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) [sample 1](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/ndk-tutorial/) [sample 2](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html)

**Step1:** First create a project then create a folder named jni in your project directory

**Step2:** Create addition.c file in jni folder and add the below lines.

```
#include "com_ndkadd_Addition.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_ndkadd_Addition_messageFromNativeCode

(JNIEnv * env, jobject jObj,jint value1, jint value2)
{

return (value1 + value2);

}
```

**Step3:** Create Android.mk file in jni folder and the below code

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := Addition
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := addition.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Step4:** navigate to bin folder of your project from command prompt. type the below line and press enter.

```
javah -jni com.ndkadd.Addition
```

**Step5:** Move the created **com_ndkadd_Addition.h** file to jni folder.

**Step6:** Now Compiling the Native Code as below from command prompt.

```
location_of_ndk\project_name> location_of_ndk\ndk-build
```

**Step7:** below the code code for your activity and usage of created .so file in your libs folder.

```
public class Addition extends Activity {
    TextView txtHello;

    static
    {
    System.loadLibrary("Addition");
    }
    public native int messageFromNativeCode(int v1,int v2);
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView txtHello = new TextView(this);
        txtHello.setText(""+messageFromNativeCode(5,5));        
        setContentView(txtHello);        
    }
}
```

**Note::** Better to have NDK in the place where you have SDK and the project containing JNI in android-ndk-r8 folder.